# Retrieving binary data from SQL table in JAVA with Byte array and BitSet class

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, bitset

Table Structure - Column X(Binary (15),null)

Value in Column X - 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

i.e 15x8=120 bits

SQL query

```
Select X from tablename;
```

Java Code part for retrieving value: `barray` is `byte[]` and `bits` is `new BitSet()`.

```
barray = resultset.getBytes("X");

if(barray != null) {
   for (int i = 0; i < barray.length * 8; i++) {
      if ((barray[barray.length-i/8-1]&(1<<(i%8))) > 0) {
         bits.set(i);
      }
   }
}
```

Problem: The 2nd if statement is returning false value(not sure y?) thus the bits object is not getting populated. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: **Java code part:barray= resultSet.getBytes("X"); if(barray!=null){ for (int i=0; i<barray.length*8; i++) { if ((barray[barray.length-i/8-1]&(1<<(i%8))) >= 0) { bits.set(i); } } }**

Comment: What bytes are you getting? Just print them out, to see if you're getting nonzero data out of the DB -- then you can figure out whether the problem is in the DB read or in the BitSet transcoding.

Comment: for the next time: you can format your source by putting 4 spaces before it, or using `` to wrap it inline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your mistake is outside of the code you posted, as I wrapped it in this program, and it works here:

```
package de.fencing_game.paul.examples;

import java.util.BitSet;

/**
 * Test class for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391097/retrieving-binary-data-from-sql-table-in-java-with-byte-array-and-bitset-class.
 */
public class BitSetByteArrayTest {


    public static void main(String[] params) {

        byte[] barray= new byte[]{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x08,
                                   0x10, 0x20, 0x40, (byte)0x80,
                                   };
        BitSet bits = new BitSet();

        if(barray!=null){
            for (int i=0; i<barray.length*8; i++) {
                if ((barray[barray.length-i/8-1]&(1<<(i%8))) > 0) {
                    bits.set(i);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(bits);
    }
}
```

It works also with your input

```
    byte[] barray = { 0,    0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0x20, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                      0,    0, 0, 0, 0};
```

instead of the sample array, showing `{77}` then.

Comment: @JavaBits: What was the reason?